# Braucht es ein Komma in „es erfreut mich jemanden gefunden zu haben”?

Tags: punctuation, comma

Ich habe in einem anderen Forum etwas gepostet und jemand hat mir in gehobenem Deutsch zurückgeschrieben, meine Wortwahl entspreche nicht den deutschen Regeln und Vorschriften. Jedoch sehe ich bei einem seiner Sätze einen möglichen Kommafehler:

> Welche schöne Ansichten sie pflegen, es erfreut mich noch jemanden gefunden zu haben, der sich dieses Werkes so erfreut.

Braucht es nach dem *es erfreut mich* nicht noch ein Komma? Oder ist es ein Spezialfall, bei dem noch das Komma auflöst.

Comment: "Aus dem Bauch heraus" finde ich den Beispielsatz ziemlich unübersichtlich, da anstelle des ersten Kommas besser ein Punkt stünde. Lässt man dort das "schwächere" Komma stehen, dann ist es fast konsequent, auf das Komma nach "mich" zu verzichten. Wie gesagt, besser fände ich eine klarere Strukturierung: "... sie pflegen. Es erfreut mich, noch jemanden gefunden zu haben...". Im Übrigen stimme ich Jan uneingeschränkt zu.

Comment: Ich denke, es sollte "welch schöne" sein. (Ansonsten "welche schönen".)

Comment: Es fehlt Kontext, um es genau sagen zu können, aber das _sie_ sieht verdächtig nach einem _Sie_ aus.

Comment: @CarstenS Ja, _welch schöne Ansicht[en]_,  _welche schöne Ansicht_ und _welche schönen Ansichten_ klingen allesamt nicht nur besser, sondern sogar korrekter als _welche schöne Ansichten_. Das erste Komma würde ich durch ein anderes Interpunktionszeichen ersetzen.

Comment: "Es erfreut mich, noch jemanden gefunden zu haben" oder "es erfreut mich noch, jemanden gefunden zu haben"?

Answer (score 7):

Relevant ist § 75 der [amtlichen deutschen Rechtschreibregeln](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf):

> Infinitivgruppen grenzt man mit Komma ab, wenn eine der folgenden Bedingungen erfüllt ist.
>
> (1) Die Infinitivgruppe ist mit *um, ohne, statt, anstatt, außer, als* eingeleitet: [Beispiele]
>
> (2) Die Infinitivgruppe hängt von einem Substantiv ab: [Beispiele]
>
> (3) Die Infinitivgruppe hängt von einem Korrelat oder einem Verweiswort ab (siehe § 77(5)): [Beispiele]
>
> E1: Wenn ein bloßer Infinitiv vorliegt, können in den Fallgruppen (2) und (3) die Kommas weggelassen werden, sofern keine Missverständnisse entstehen: [Beispiele]
>
> E2: In den Fällen, die nicht durch § 75(1) bis (3) geregelt sind, kann ein Komma gesetzt werden, um die Gliederung deutlich zu machen bzw. um Missverständnisse auszuschließen. Dasselbe gilt für Partizip-, Adjektiv- und entsprechende Wortgruppen (siehe § 77(7) und § 78(3)).

Hier trifft § 75(3) zu; der Infinitiv hängt vom Korrelat *es* ab. § 75 E1 trifft nicht zu, denn es handelt sich um einen erweiterten Infinitiv. Nach meiner Ansicht müsste ein Komma gesetzt werden. Eines der amtlichen Beispiele für § 75(3) ist sehr nah an deinem, nämlich:

> Es missfällt mir, diesen Vertrag zu unterzeichnen.

§ 78(3) gibt meines Erachtens nicht her, dass das Komma optional würde, und es sind auch keine vergleichbaren Beispiele dort.

---

Obligatorischer Nachtrag: Ich warne vor Fingerzeigen und Nachtreten, die führen in der Regel nicht zum gewünschten Effekt.

Comment: Ich werde ganz klar nicht mehr mit solchen Leuten diskutieren. Es fällt mir zwar schwer, mich nicht zu verteidigen, doch ich habe keine Lust mehr, mich mit diesen passiv-aggressiven Leuten zu prügeln. Zudem hat er seine Nachricht mit diesem Satz beendet: _Dies ist kein Tadel, sondern ein Appell, ihren Stiel zu behalten und zu verbessern, um zu einer prachtvollen Sprachgewandtheit zu finden._ Ich werde immer wieder mit solcher Kritik konfrontiert. Sei es von der Schule her oder halt von irgendwelchen Leuten im Internet.

Comment: @Fenrir Echt, der hat *Stiel* in dem Satz geschrieben? Lol! (Mehr kann einem dazu nicht einfallen x3)

Comment: Haha, habe ich erst jetzt bemerkt!